# Evaluate the integral $\int_c^{\infty}(1-e^{-abc^{m}x^{-m}d})xdx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to know how to solve the following integration $$\int_c^{\infty}(1-e^{-abc^{m}x^{-m}d})xdx$$ where $a,b,c,d,m$ are all greater than $0$. I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: I suppose that the incomplete gamma function could appear in the antiderivative.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes it does appear as i have seen the indefinite integral in the wolfram alpha. I want to know the steps as the wolfram alpha only shows the answer but not step by step solution

Comment: I hope that $m>2$. Then the change of variable $u=abdc^m/x^m$ yields the result.

Comment: @Did yes $m>2$. I do not know how it will converge because the first term in paranthesis goes to infinity ($\int_c^{\infty}xdx$). How to make it converge to a finite value? can you provide some steps with the change of variable that you used?

Comment: Did you try to apply the change of variable I suggested? Then convergence becomes obvious...

Comment: @Did yes i tried and solved it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Post an answer then?

Comment: @Did i posted the answer.

Comment: I think you missed a couple of useless extra parameters, try with $abduv^2w$ :)

Comment: @Did I am sorry for being off question. But I will be very thankful if you could comment on this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094428/where-am-i-wrong-in-the-following-strategy). I have a lot of confusion about this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FrankMoses Yeah, I had read it, and I have nothing to say apart that the "strategy" you suggest does not compute the quantity you are interested in. Analytically, one may write this quantity as an integral of dimension $(L+1)M$, but the formula one gets is quite useless hence simulations might be your only option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer to the question (after putting the substitution of Did) $$-\frac{1}{2}c^2-\frac{(abdc^m)^{\frac{2}{m}}}{m}\{\Gamma(\frac{-2}{m})-\Gamma(\frac{-2}{m},abd)\}$$ Thanks Did.